# Do you have to declare the level of the spell prior to rolling the attack or saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you are in combat do you have to state the spell slot level you intend to use for the spell prior to rolling for ranged spell attack/the targets save throw? It seems like you would but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! When you've got the time, please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour); it's a great introduction to the site, plus you can earn a badge.

Answer (score 29):

### Yes.

When a character casts a spell, the PHB refers to expending a spell slot (PHB 114, for Wizards):

> To cast one of these spells, you must expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher.

This means that the caster must choose the spell slot to expend before casting the spell, and cannot change the spell slot that was expended based on its results.

### Casting a Spell is like Choosing a Weapon

The barbarian has to commit to a specific weapon before making their attack, and the ranger has to commit to a particular arrow before shooting it. Likewise, a caster must commit to the spell and spell slot they will expend when they cast it, and can't change it depending on the outcome of the roll.

Comment: @Chemus Whoops, snark wasn't my intention. Is this edit better? Also, while this might be obvious to experienced players, I can easily see how a newer player (or one angling for an advantage) might be confused about this.

Comment: Yes, that changed the tone, to my eyes.